# Как оперировать шириной .navbar-brand в Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Есть такой навбар, сайдбар и контент:

```css
.navbar-brand,
.sidebar-box {
  border-right: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav nav">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 hidden-xs hidden-sm sidebar-box">Sidebar Box</div>
    <div class="col-md-10">Content Box</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dNWZJX

---

Как оперировать шириной `.navbar-brand` — чтобы она соотвествовала `.col-md-2`?

Мне нужно, что пункты навбара начинались на одном уровне с контентом, то есть чтобы правая граница `.navbar-brand` и `.sidebar-box` совпадали (при `md` и `lg`, так как в случае `xs` и `md` сайдбар скрывается).

[image: Bootstrap - Ширина .navbar-brand]

Я имею в виду средствами Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему, добавив следующее в свой файл стилей:

```
.navbar-header {
  min-width: 16%;
}
```

---

```css
.navbar-brand,
.sidebar-box {
  border-right: 1px solid red;
}

.navbar-header {
  min-width: 16%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Lorem Ipsum</a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav nav">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 hidden-xs hidden-sm sidebar-box">Sidebar Box</div>
    <div class="col-md-10">Content Box</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GrmGmK